# VMWare PowerCLI API to Login to a Guest VM

Tags: vmware, virtual-machine, provisioning, powercli

I would like to automate the creation and provioning of a VM using a CI server (like Team City). I found that there is a PowerCLI API available that allows you to manage virtual machines but my question is ...

After creating a VM definition(Virtual Hardware Definition - NOT OS INSTALLATION YET). Is it possible to install the OS and create a user on the target guest VM or is it better to create an image manually with at least one super user and then control everything using Chef or Puppet?.

Answer (score 0):

You can create something called a [Customization Specification](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc_50%2FGUID-7523239A-9BB8-4FAD-88F6-C8701933CA64.html) that will allow you to create, clone, or deploy a Virtual Machine.  With the Customization Specification you can define user credentials and so on and deploy it via **VMware vSphere PowerCLI** like so:

```
Get-VM VM | New-VM -VMHost Host -Datastore Storage1 -OSCustomizationSpec ClientSpec -Name VM1
```

See the [VMware vSphere Power CLI User's Guide](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI501/doc/vsph_powercli_usg501.pdf) for more detail.